# Load Self Referencing Entity With EF Core 5.0 ( Just get Parents and their children in their navigation property )

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1, self-reference, ef-core-5.0

I want to implement a Commenting System this is my Comment Entity.

```
 public class Comment
    {
        public int CommentId { get; set; }
        public int? ParentId  { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset DateCreated { get; set; }
        public DateTimeOffset DateModified { get; set; }


        public Comment Parent { get; set; }
        public ICollection<Comment> Children { get; set; }


    }
```

and this is my configs in Fluent API

```
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Comment>(comment =>
            {
                comment.HasKey(c => c.CommentId);
                comment.HasIndex(c => c.ParentId);

                comment.HasOne(c => c.Parent)
                       .WithMany(c => c.Children)
                       .HasForeignKey(c => c.ParentId);
            });
        }
```

everything is ok and I can load all records with hierarchy ( include parent and children ) with this code

```
  List<Comment> comments = await _db.Comments.Include(c => c.Children)
                .ToListAsync();
```

but this code load all elements such as children. But I want to load all Parents and then their childs and then grand childs and ....

I use this code for this scenario

```
List<Comment> comments = await _db.Comments.Include(c => c.Children)
                .Where(c => c.ParentId == null)
                .ToListAsync();
```

and this code just load all parents with their children and not grand chilren and more in hierarchy.

How should I write this query ?

Comment: That is a very complicated query, I recommend writing it in a stored procedure or table-valued function on the server, and query that from EF instead. EF has no concept of cursors, and I believe you'll find that you'll need them. Or at least really precise CTE queries.

Comment: Please look for other questions on LINQ + hierarchy or recursive. This is a continually recurring topic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found solution for this scenario.

```
  public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {

            List<Comment> comments = await _db.Comments.AsNoTrackingWithIdentityResolution()
                                                        .Include(c => c.Children)
                                                        .ToListAsync();

            // Structure Comments into a tree
            List<Comment> commentsTree = comments.Where(c => c.ParentId == null)
                                                 .AsParallel()
                                                 .ToList();

            return View(commentsTree);
        }
```